# How can I make the if statement contain more than one item?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am extremely new to python and programming in general so please excuse my stupidity. But can I make if be able to search for more than one thing? so like..

```
choice = input()
if choice == "Yes" or "Sure" or "Yep":
     print("You chose yes")

elif choice == "No" or "Nah" or "Nope":
     print("You chose no")
```

And don't worry I know the or command isn't used correctly here because I've tried it and it obviously doesn't work, so how can i make it work?
Please explain how and why it works like this as you must remember I'm new to this stuff, so basically ELI5.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you can go with

```
choice = input()
if choice == "Yes" or choice == "Sure" or choice == "Yep":
    print("You chose yes")

elif choice == "No" or choice == "Nah" or choice == "Nope":
    print("You chose no")
```

Why your code didn't work:
In the condition

```
if choice == "Yes" or "Sure" or "Yep":
```

each part separated by `or` will evaluate to a boolean value.

`"Sure"`,`"Yep"` will always evaluate to `true`

```
>>> bool("Sure")
True
```

Comment: Thanks hah wow I knew it was going to be something simple and stupid like that because I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: @TOASTED PIE, you're telling me ;) I was just thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
choice = input()
if choice in {"Yes", "Sure", "Yep"}:
    print("You chose yes")
elif choice in {"No", "Nah", "Nope"}:
    print("You chose no")
```